# ScrapySplash cannot find elements with ":" in classname

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm using Srcapy with Splash to crawl a website using a java framework named IFaces. This frameworks use values like "_id35:_id48" for element's ID and classnames.

When I crawl the site with Splash and try to select an element with this value I got an DOM Exception 12, probably because the ":" character used in the values. I already tried to escape the value (ie.: "_id35\3a_id48" and _id35\3a _id48) but still got the same error.

Is there  any other way for me to select those elements (like XPath)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with [splash:select](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-select) within a Lua script, in that way you can select by class name like this :

```
splash:select('.element')
```

or by id like this:

```
splash:select('#_id35:_id48')
```

Take a look at the [CSS selector documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), I'm sure that you will find a way to achieve what you want.

Take a look at [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043672/splash-lua-script-to-do-multiple-clicks-and-visits#38120568), for some examples on how to use js with splash.